# Generate Binary Contents of an XML File

Tags: c#

I have a column called `contents` in a table called `File` in SQL Server 2008. The `content` column's data type is `varbinary(MAX)`. I have an XML file and I need to generate its content in binary using c#.net 3.5.

The name of the file is `Test.XML` and I need to generate its contents in a file called `Test.txt`. Then I can write a update script to set its contents.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate its content in binary"??? What do you try to do here?? Not clear at all..... to store an XML file, use the `XML` datatype - not varbinary.... And is your **column** called `content` or `contents` ...

Comment: Well, suppose we have a XML , I read all the contents in Text using File.ReadAllText method. Then I want to write the contents in another file using BinaryWriter.  I hope I have made myself clear. Sorry about not making myself clear last time.

Comment: Yeah I'm also a bit lost here. Do you need to save the xml file into the field "contents" in the database?

Comment: Why do you insist on turning that XML into binary??? Doesn't make any sense at all..... XML is just a string - just store it into a column of type `XML` and be done with it....

Comment: I agree that it doesnt make sense, when we have a column of type XML. But what I have described is what I need to accomplish. If you guys can come out with suggestions, it is much appreciated!

Comment: it's how the application is architected. Unfortunately, I dont have much say about that.

Comment: I **still** don't understand how you want to convert XML into a "binary" format... what do you need to do there?? Do you just need to store the XML into the `VARBINARY` column??

Comment: yes I need to store the XML into varbinary form.

Comment: he clearly just needs to read the contents of an xml file, convert it to binary, then save it to the db field

Comment: yes exactly as dormisher stated. Now any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file, convert to a byte array, then just stick the byte array into the varbinary field in your db:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText("text.xml");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);

// put bytes into db
```

***UPDATE:***

If you really do want it as a string representation of 0's and 1's - pointless as that seems to me, you just need iterate through the byte array and convert each byte to base 2 binary and add said value to a string builder object like this:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText("text.xml");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (byte b in bytes)
{
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2));
}

File.WriteAllText("test2.txt", sb.ToString());
```

I don't want anyone to vote me down for this seemingly silly answer - look at the comments below this is what he says he wants.

***UPDATE:***

To convert the byte array to hex do the following:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText("text.xml");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (byte b in bytes)
{
      sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
}

File.WriteAllText("test2.txt", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Okay, but I need to write this bytes into a file and copy and update the sql script. I tried doing this: string xmlData = File.ReadAllText(inputFilePath); byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlData); FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate); BinaryWriter sw = new BinaryWriter(fs); sw.Write(bytes); sw.Close(); the inary output file shows me the same content in XML. Arent we supposed to see vague numbers which dont make any sense.

Comment: Here is how they are pulling the binary contents from the database   string fileContentsDecoded = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(specsXML);

Comment: I don't really undertand why you need to do this - why do you need to store the xml as 1's and 0's? It doesn't make any sense. Even the xml file is binary really, as is every file on a computer, what you are talking about is not converting to binary but getting a string representation of binary where for each byte we have the representative ASCII characters 1 and 0...is that what you want to do? you will end up with a much larger file that the original xml file.

Comment: @user424294 you are aware that varbinary(max) in sql doesn't expect a string of '101010' - it just takes in a byte array (from the .Net world) and stores it.  Equally, if you need to turn it into a binary literal for a dynamic SQL statement you need HEX encoding `0x4E9ABC2...`

Comment: @dormisher - update your answer to show how to turn a binary array into a hex string and you've got a +1 from me.